# Show count of columns distinct values

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, ado

Hello my fellow colleagues from StackOverflow!

I will be brief, and cut to the point:
I have a table in MS Access, it contains 2 columns of interest- County, and TGTE (Type Of Geothermal Energy ). Column TGTE is of type VARCHAR and it can have 1 of two values, to make it easier let's say it is either L or H.

I need to create SQL query that shows a result which is described bellow:

Bellow is the part of the table:

---

```
County | TGTE | ... |   
First  |   L  |
First  |   L  |
First  |   H  |
Second |   H  |
Third  |   L  |
__________________
```

I need a resulting query that shows the count of distinct TGTE in every County like this:

---

```
County | TGTE = L | TGTE = H |    
First  |    2     |     1    |
Second |    0     |     1    |
Third  |    1     |     0    |
__________________________________
```

How can I create query that displays the desired result described above ?

---

NOTE:
I have browsed through archive, and found similar things, but nothing to help me.
To be honest, I do not know how to formulate the question properly, so I guess that is why Google couldn't be of much help...

I have tried with this:

```
    SELECT County, COUNT(TGTE) as [Something]
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE TGTE = "L"
    GROUPBY COUNTY;
```

but this is the result I get:

```
County | TGTE = L |     
First  |    2     |  
Second |    0     |    
Third  |    1     |   
__________________________________
```

If I change L to H, in the query above, I get this:

```
County |  TGTE = H |   
First  |     1    |
Second |     1    |
Third  |     0    |
__________________________________
```

I work on Windows XP, in C++, using ADO to access an MS Access 2007 database.
If there is anything else that I can do to help, ask and I will gladly do it.

### EDIT #1:

After trying Declan's solution this is what I get:

Values in main table:

```
|    County    | TGTE |

| Стари Град   |  H   |

|    Сурчин    |  L   |

| Стари Град   |  H   |

| Савски Венац |  H   |

|   Раковица   |  H   |
```

Output :

```
|    County    | TGTE = L | TGTE = H | 

|   Раковица   |      1   |     1    | 

| Савски Венац |      1   |     0    |

|    Сурчин    |      1   |     0    |

| Стари Град   |      1   |     0    |
```

It should output this:

```
|    County    | TGTE = L | TGTE = H | 

|   Раковица   |      1   |     0    | 

| Савски Венац |      1   |     0    |

|    Сурчин    |      0   |     1    |

| Стари Град   |      2   |     0    |
```

### EDIT #2:

On Declan's request, here is the original query I use:

```
   wchar_t *query = L"select Општина, \
                      sum( iif( Тип_геотермалне_енергије = 
                                    'Хидрогеотермална енергија', 1, 0 ) ) as [HGTE], \
                      sum( iif(  Тип_геотермалне_енергије = 
                                    'Литогеотермална енергија', 1, 0 ) ) as [LGTE] \
                      from Објекат \
                      group by Општина; ";
```

Translated to our example, it looks like this:

```
   wchar_t *query = L"select County, \
                      sum( iif( TGTE = 'H', 1, 0 ) ) as [HGTE], \
                      sum( iif( TGTE = 'L', 1, 0 ) ) as [LGTE] \
                      from MyTable \
                      group by County; ";
```

### EDIT #3:

After I copy the above query in Access and run it, everything works fine, thus I believe that the problem lies in in usage of ADO.

### EDIT #4:

After browsing through Internet, I am sure that problem is ADO.
How can I use IIF() in ADO so my query can work?
If it can't be done, than how to modify y query to do what I have described above?

Comment: have you tried using count (distinct TGTE) ?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that it isn't supported by Access. I have found several articles here with that topic.

Comment: Please post the SQL statement that you are using. Also, you may want to do all this in a QUERY within the Access DB and then retrieve the data to your C++ app by calling that QUERY object.

Comment: you might want to check this blog site. http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reworked Deslan's query like bellow, and it works:

```
   SELECT  County
           ,sum( switch( ТGTE = 'L', 1, TGTE = 'H', 0 ) ) as [L_Count]
           ,sum( switch( ТGTE = 'H', 1, TGTE = 'L', 0 ) ) as [H_Count]
   FROM    MyTable
   GROUP BY
           County;
```

Everything works fine, when I run it through ADO and MS Access 2007.

I do not understand why IIF() isn't working in ADO, maybe it is not supported or something...

Thank you Declan anyway, for your solution.You have +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the iif function within the two additional columns. Here is some pseudo code to get you started.

```
SELECT  County
        ,sum(iif(TGTE = "L",1,0)) as [L_Count]
        ,sum(iif(TGTE = "H",1,0)) as [H_Count]
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY
        COUNTY;
```

Comment: Thanks Declan, can you provide some links for syntax? This will be my first time using it. I will also browse the Google to try to find an example. I hope it works for MS Access... Thank you.

Comment: Use the "Function Builder" in the Access Query Designer and you will find both the SUM and IIF functions right there.

Comment: Declan, I am almost there... I will update my question, because it will illustrate my current problem best.

Comment: It works fine, when I am making a query in Access! Problem must be in filling in the list view or something...

Comment: Declan, do you have any idea why this query doesn't work in C++, when I use ADO ?

Comment: No, I don't. but why are you not going with the Access QUERY option, if that is working?

Comment: Declan, I have substituted IIF() with SWITCH() statement and it works. Does this give you any hint as to why IIF doesn't work? Is SWITCH() statement acceptable? If it is, you could update your solution, so I can accept it.

Comment: Declan, I have decided to stick with switch statement, since I am in time trouble at this moment. Still, I have upvoted your answer. Thank you very much for everything!